# still cannot get the apache server get access to database after added www-data to certain group

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, flask, sqlalchemy

here is the code to connect sqlalchemy session to database file

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from DB_setup_alchemy import Base,User,Visitor,VisitRecord
from os import getcwd

# link to the DB we are using
# pay attention to this part, if without check_same_thread=false, there will be lots of errors
# but what is going on behind this part of code
# what does engine and session really means
db_path='sqlite:///'+getcwd()+'/data.db'
print(db_path)
engine = create_engine(db_path,connect_args={'check_same_thread': False})
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()
```

all files of my project is in flaskapp folder

```
drwxrwxr-x 9 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 11 20:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Apr 11 04:11 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 11 04:31 .aws
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 11 20:38 flaskapp
drwx------ 2 root   ubuntu 4096 Apr 11 20:11 test
```

files in flaskapp folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 11 20:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 11 20:09 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   345 Apr 11 16:37 AWS_API.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 11 17:37 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   296 Apr 11 16:23 app.wsgi
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 20480 Apr 11 17:37 data.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  7426 Apr 11 20:38 flaskapp.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     6 Apr 11 04:34 index.html
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 11 16:46 templates
drwxrwxr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 11 16:13 venv
```

both data.db and folder flask have permissions for users in group ubuntu, and I can see that user www-data is also in group ubuntu:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-93:~/flaskapp$ groups ubuntu
ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip www-data video plugdev lxd netdev
```

but if I type: groups www-data

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-93:~/flaskapp$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data
```

Here is the error information:

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-93:~/flaskapp$ cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Sat Apr 11 20:57:03.891126 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26861:tid 140079813093120] [client 209.6.74.140:53631] ERROR:flaskapp:Exception on / [GET]
[Sat Apr 11 20:57:03.891160 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26861:tid 140079813093120] [client 209.6.74.140:53631] Traceback (most recent call last):
..............
[Sat Apr 11 20:57:03.891568 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26861:tid 140079813093120] [client 209.6.74.140:53631] sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
[Sat Apr 11 20:57:03.891574 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26861:tid 140079813093120] [client 209.6.74.140:53631] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
[Sat Apr 11 20:57:03.891581 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 26861:tid 140079813093120] [client 209.6.74.140:53631]
```

Here is the error from browser:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

I have tried simple print hello web app and it's working.
So, I was wondering what should I do to change owner or file permissions to get my flask app working?

Comment: It still does not work even I changed permissions of data.db file and flaskapp folder to 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You showed us output for `$ groups ubuntu` and `$ groups www-data`.
It indicates that `ubuntu` has group-write permission to e.g. append
to a `664` file in group `www-data`.

But your webserver is running as user `www-data` rather than `ubuntu`,
so that is not relevant. What *does* matter is that `www-data` wants
to belong to the `ubuntu` group in order to write to the current DB file,
but it is not in that group. You could edit `/etc/groups` to remedy that.

Alternatively you might want to `$ sudo chgrp www-data data.db` (or chown)
to grant the apache web user access to that file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Bu I added www-data to ubuntu then if I type groups www-data, the response becomes www-data: www-data  ubuntu. I think this indicates that www-data is added into group ubuntu, but it still does not work after I restarted the apache.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out by myself what is the problem:
the bug behind this problem is that apache user is different from ubuntu. So when apache is running my web app, it is running from a different working directory, and of course cannot find the database file.

So, I first changed path of database .db file in my code to correct absolute path like this:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:////home/ubuntu/flaskproject/data.db',connect_args={'check_same_thread': False})
```

then change owner of the project folder and database file to be www-data (apache user):

```
sudo chown www-data .
sudo chown www-data data.db
```

and also make sure that owner has read and write permission to project folder and data.db file (which is already satisfied in my case)

Another solution to solve the permission problem is that add user www-data to group ubuntu, so we do not need to change owner of the project folder and data.db file (but make sure that user in ubuntu group has read and write permissions)

```
usermod -a -G ubuntu www-data
```

So in general, as long as the path of database is correct (suggest absolute path) and user www-data has permission to project folder and database file, everything should work fine.